# Sentence structure of "We made them walk to the school"

Tags: grammar, sentence

I came across the following sentence in a book:

> We made them walk.

I see it conveys a different meaning compared to:

> We made coffee.

In the second sentence the structure is **Subject + Verb + Object**.
But I'm finding it a bit difficult to identify the parts in the first sentence.
I feel *them* or *walk* cannot be objects of the sentence. Any help?

Comment: You are half-right. It's called a catenative construction, where "them" is object of "made" and "walk" is a subordinate clause functioning as complement of "made".

Comment: Like  `We made them coffee` ? Here `them` is the `Indirect Object` of the verb `made`.   If I understand correctly `We made coffee` is meaningful, but `We made walk` isn't. I'm going to google `catenative construction`... Thank you @BillJ :)

Answer (score 4):

> *We made them walk*.

This is a catenative construction.

"Make" is a catenative verb and "walk" is a subordinate clause functioning as catenative complement of "make".

The intervening noun phrase "them" is the syntactic object of "make" and the semantic (understood) subject of the subordinate clause. It's called a 'raised' object because the verb that "them" relates to is higher in the constituent structure than the one it relates to semantically.

The term 'catenative' comes from the Latin word for "chain", which is appropriate here because the verbs "make" and "walk" do indeed form a chain, separated only by the NP "them".

Comment: for=form? . . .

Comment: What's the difference between 'catenative verb' and 'causative verb'? I thought 'made' was causative in 'I made him [verb]'. It's confusing now

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Yes, as it happens "make" belongs to the subtype of verbs called 'causative'. But that's not a requirement of the catenative construction. Compare "I promised to read the report" (simple catenative) and "I promised Sue to read the report" (complex catenative with intervening object).